# Is there a way to backup my hotkeys (on Xubuntu)?

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard

I use certain hotkeys/keyboard shortcuts from the keyboard (type in keyboard in the menu) and window manager (type in Window Manager in the menu). Sometimes I like to test different ubuntu based distributions. Is there a way to back up these hot keys? I like to take my hotkeys with me when I upgrade ubuntu or install it on a new computer.

I am using Ubuntu 15.04 on one computer and 14.04.3 on my other computer. Both are Xubuntu editions.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Could you please give us a bit more information like: what version of Ubuntu you're running? Do you mean shortcut keys?  How do you define them?  Please [edit] your question and add this information... Then leave a comment @Fabby.

Comment: I edited the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open up terminal and type:

```
cp ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml /path/to/target/directory/
```

All keyboard shortcuts under both `Keyboard > Application Shortcuts` and also `Window Manager > Keyboard` are stored in this file. Whenever I do a fresh install, one of the first things I do is copy this file over the previous one. Then you can log out and in again, and all your shortcuts are there. For other desktop environments the file will be in a different place. There is no difference in file location between Xubuntu 14.04 and 15.04 or between Xfce 4.10 and 4.12.

Answer (score 3):

To back-up your shortcut keys, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal and type:

```
gsettings list-recursively org.freedesktop.ibus.general.hotkey > keys.back-up
gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys >> keys.backup
gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings >> keys.backup
```

To restore them, put `gsettings set` before each line in `keys.backup` and execute it.

For more information type `man gsettings`

Comment: I am getting a "No such schema" error for the first two.  I should also note that I am using XFCE. The third executes with no errors but where is this being saved?

Comment: Maybe I should've put it in the title but the fact that I am using xubuntu is the last sentence of the question. The last one works for window manager but not keyboard setting. They keyboard settings is more for hot keys to apps. Yes, in xfce, there are two separate places where you can edit different kinds of hotkeys. Therefore I will give you a plus. If you can find the equivalent for keyboard, I will give you the check mark as well. Edit: It says I need 15 reputation before I can upvote anything.

Comment: Well, how did you find the code after list-recursively? I AM running xfce after all. Maybe we can work from there. I've got a backup script for ubuntu that I'd love to integrate this into

Comment: You should delete all these comments.  It's starting to look like a chat room here.  **;-)** (Done already with mine) As stated before: I don't have Xubuntu, do if you have any further questions, just [ask another one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)!